# Tonejs sequencer does not recognise variables into an object

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, p5.js, tone.js

I am trying to build an object that contains a sequencer using p5.js, p5.sound library and tone.js

The problem is that my code does not recognise the variables written in one function that is inside one object.

All other functions inside class tr909 can recognise the variables that I declared in the class constructor,  but the variable "sequence" doesn't recognise them.

As you can see below, tr909 class has sX and sY variables , but when I am in the function called sequence ( inside the tr909 class, on the bottom), this function won't recognise the variables anymore.

do you know why this happen?

thanks ! :)

```
 //object 
let tr9091;
let bL9091 = 16; //beat lenght

let posX9091 = 100; //positionX 909
let posY9091 = 220; //positionY 909

let sX9091 = 320; //sizeX of 909
let sY9091 = 60; //sizeY of 909

// var cellWidth = sX9091 / bL9091; //dont know why, if I put it in constructor of 909 object, sequence function does not recognise cellWidth

//Pre-load  audio files 
let hh909, clp909m, bd909;

let time;
let beatIndex;
var sX;
let sequence;
// var sX = 1;

function preload() {

  bd909 = loadSound('assets/bass_sample.mp3');
  hh909 = loadSound('assets/hh_sample.mp3');
  clp909 = loadSound('assets/clap_sample.mp3');

}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 400);

  tr9091 = new tr909(bd909, hh909, clp909, bL9091, posX9091, posY9091, sX9091, sY9091);


}

function draw() {

}

function keyPressed() {
  if (key === ' ') {
    tr9091.clicked();
  }
}

function mousePressed() {
  tr9091.rectPressed();
}

class tr909 {

constructor(bd, hh, clp, beatLenght, pX, pY, sX, sY) {
    //variables 
    this.bd = bd;
    this.hh = hh;
    this.clp = clp;

    this.beatLenght = beatLenght;


    this.pX = pX; //positionX 909
    this.pY = pY; //positionY 909

    this.sX = sX; //sizeX 909
    this.sY = sY; //sizeY 909

    this.cellWidth = this.sX / this.beatLenght;


    //sequences
    this.bdPat = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0];
    this.hhPat = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1];
    this.clpPat = [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0];

    this.sPat = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16];

    this.cursorPos = 0;

    //phrases
    this.bdPhrase = new p5.Phrase('bd', (time) => {
      this.bd.play(time)
    }, this.bdPat);

    this.hhPhrase = new p5.Phrase('hh', (time) => {
      this.hh.play(time)
    }, this.hhPat);

    this.clpPhrase = new p5.Phrase('clp', (time) => {
      this.clp.play(time)
    }, this.clpPat);


    //parts
    this.drums = new p5.Part();


    //adding phrase to parts
    this.drums.addPhrase(this.bdPhrase);
    this.drums.addPhrase(this.hhPhrase);
    this.drums.addPhrase(this.clpPhrase);

    this.drums.addPhrase('seq', this.sequence, this.sPat);



    //BPM
    let bpmCTRL;
    this.bpmCTRL = createSlider(30, 120, 120, 1);
    this.bpmCTRL.position(pX + 10, pY + 70);
    this.bpmCTRL.input(() => {
      this.drums.setBPM(this.bpmCTRL.value())
    });
    this.drums.setBPM('120');

    this.drawMatrix();

  } //final constructor


  clicked() { //play loop
    this.drums.loop();
  }

  rectPressed() {
    //Y mouse click inside the object 
    if ((mouseY > this.pY && mouseY < this.pY + this.sY) && (mouseX > this.pX && mouseX < this.pX + this.sX)) {
      this.rowClicked = floor(3 * (mouseY - this.pY) / this.sY);
      this.indexClicked = floor(16 * (mouseX - this.pX) / this.sX);

      if (this.rowClicked === 0) {
        console.log("firstrow " + this.indexClicked);
        this.bdPat[this.indexClicked] = +!this.bdPat[this.indexClicked];
      } else if (this.rowClicked === 1) {
        console.log("secondtrow");
        this.hhPat[this.indexClicked] = +!this.hhPat[this.indexClicked];
      } else if (this.rowClicked === 2) {
        console.log("thrtrow");
        this.clpPat[this.indexClicked] = +!this.clpPat[this.indexClicked];
      }
      this.drawMatrix();
    }
  }



//visual interface
  drawMatrix() {

    fill(80);
    stroke('gray');
    strokeWeight(2);
    rect(this.pX, this.pY, this.sX, this.sY);


    stroke('gray');
    strokeWeight(2);

    //vertical lines
    for (let i = 0; i < this.beatLenght; i++) {
      line(this.pX + i * this.cellWidth, this.pY, this.pX + i * this.cellWidth, this.pY + this.sY);
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      line(this.pX, this.pY + i * this.sY / 3, this.pX + this.sX, this.pY + i * this.sY / 3);
    }

    //draw circles

    for (let i = 0; i < this.beatLenght; i++) {
      if (this.bdPat[i] === 1) {
        ellipse(this.pX + i * this.cellWidth + 0.5 * this.cellWidth, this.pY + this.sY / 6, 10);
      }
      if (this.hhPat[i] === 1) {
        ellipse(this.pX + i * this.cellWidth + 0.5 * this.cellWidth, this.pY + this.sY / 2, 10);
      }
      if (this.clpPat[i] === 1) {
        ellipse(this.pX + i * this.cellWidth + 0.5 * this.cellWidth, this.pY + this.sY * 5 / 6, 10);
      }
    }

  }

  sequence(time, beatIndex) {

    this.cellWidth = this.sX / this.beatLenght;

    stroke('red');
    fill(255, 0, 0, 30);
    rect(beatIndex * this.cellWidth, this.sX, this.cellWidth, this.sY);
    console.log(beatIndex);
  }


} //final object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because here:

```
this.drums = new p5.Part();
//adding phrase to parts
this.drums.addPhrase(this.bdPhrase);
this.drums.addPhrase(this.hhPhrase);
this.drums.addPhrase(this.clpPhrase);
this.drums.addPhrase('seq', this.sequence, this.sPat);
```

You pass it as a callback function. Check the first answer in this thread:
[How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Either replace the argument `this.sequence` with:

```
function(){ this.sequence() }.bind( this )
```

or even shorter:

```
this.sequence.bind(this);
```

or like this:

```
()=>{ this.sequence() }
```

or, when you want to pass in arguments or return value:

```
(...args) => this.sequence(...args)
```

Comment: credits to @FZs.. Didn't mean to rollback, I added you suggestions, nice.

Comment: I've edited the last one again... Removing the brackets allows returning a value (without a return statement)

Comment: Very good. I didn't know about this. Also, I choose the simpler ones on purpose. Yours are obviously better, compacter, faster, but it's also less easy to understand. When you look at the code OP provided, It could be understandable that it's a bit out of his league right? No offence.

Comment: I wouldn't say mine are far better... Also, I haven't inspected OP's code deeply... and as I haven't seen the definition of `.addPhrase`, I don't know, what does it pass to its callback or whether it accepts return value... I think that in case of named callbacks, the best is always `callbackFn.bind(this)`, as it passes over everything, but avoids creating anonymous helper functions. Also note that the bracktless syntax works only with `=>` functions...

Comment: That function is a part of p5.Sound.js. The docs doesn't even say there is a callback. but the source does. :s idk either. 
Yeah, I understood only in single-line arrow functions.